# Android Keyboard display affect layout

Tags: android

please help me in this problem, I tried to fix it for 3 days but nothing worked.

I have a SearchView, a Fragment, an ArrayAdapter which display a list items, everything working fine but there is one problem, whenever the Keyboard display/hide when I click to the SearchView, the method getView in MyArrayAdapter is called and all the items in the List is reload which I don't wanna happens because each items have an ImageView, the image is load from url with AsyncTask. I don't know if it's normal behavior or not, please help me.

In the Fragment, create ArrayAdapter

```
        final SubjectArrayAdapter adapter = new SubjectArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUBJECT ID: " + view.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

In ArrayAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = null;
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView secondTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        firstTextView.setText(list.get(position).getSubjectName());
        secondTextView.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + list.get(position).getSubjectId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(list.get(position).getIconUrl());
        rowView.setId(list.get(position).getSubjectId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SubjectArrayAdapter!getView", e.toString());
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

The SearchView is normal SearchView, nothing specific, I changed it to an EditText and the problem still happening, I used an emulator without keyboard display and nothing happen so my only guess is the problem lies in the event display/hide of the keyboard.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks for everyone support, I found Picasso lib, wished that I know about it sooner, I just have to change 1 line of code

`new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(list.get(position).getIconUrl());`

with this one

`Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).getIconUrl()).fit().into(imageView);`

Comment: Its a normal behavior of adapter because whenever a view of list view goes invisible or comes back to visibility the adapter generates the view again and the getVIew method calls. you cant stop this.

Comment: Are you sure, I tried with playstore, but their image didn't reload like I do when I click on Search Google Play or hide it, did they not use Adapter like I do, or I use the load image the wrong way, because my I mage is clearly reload. Thank you

Comment: There image doesn't reload because they are caching the image after download and using from it next time

Comment: I see, I'll look for a way to cached then, can you suggest me a link

And how to marked my question as answered, I'm new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Hiding and showing the keyboard input causes your view to run another layout pass (because the window size has changed), which triggers the `ListView` to request the adapter to bind data to views again.

It it not good practice to start a long running download task in an adapter callback like that. There are a number of user behaviors that would cause your the framework to request those views multiple times and your app would be left spinning its wheels. If the user rotates the device, or even scrolls the list quickly, you would have the exact same problem.

Have a look at the [Efficient Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) section of the developer guide, which discusses downloading, processing, and caching techniques to properly handle bitmaps.